# Errors while compiling the generated C++ SDK

Tags: kaa

I have installed the kaa server and did a compilation of a SDK i generated, first everything went well but after i changed the IP settings in the administrative GUI of the kaa-server things went wrong.

The C++ SDK wont compile anymore and gives the following error:

```
In file included from kaa/IKaaClientStateStorage.hpp:24:0,
                 from kaa/channel/transport/IKaaTransport.hpp:20,
                 from kaa/channel/transport/AbstractKaaTransport.hpp:20,
                 from kaa/event/registration/UserTransport.hpp:22,
                 from /impl/event/registration/UserTransport.cpp:17:
kaa/notification/gen/NotificationDefinitions.hpp:34:27: error: ‘Notification’ in namespace ‘kaa_notification’ does not name a type
 typedef kaa_notification::Notification KaaNotification;
```

Comment: What version of Kaa do you use? Have you re-downloaded the SDK after changing the IP?